# explain the code line by line

Tags: c, string, recursion, reverse

I found this code in C that reverses a string. This code uses recursion and i'm not able to understand the reverse() function. Can anyone help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void reverse() //recursive function to reverse string.
    { 
        char c;
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if(c!='\n')
        { 
          reverse();
          printf("%c",c);
        }

    }

    void main()
    {
      printf("\nenter a string: ");
      reverse();
      getch();

    }
```

Comment: By printing the character _after_ calling reverse, it prints it in reverse order. Try placing the `printf` statement _before_ reverse.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://ideone.com/IR07Ts). And/or perhaps find a [tutorial on recursion](https://www.programtopia.net/c-programming/docs/recursion-c-programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reverse` function prints a `char *`/string in reverse order e.g. "question" -> "noitseuq".

It does so by reading an input string character-by-character (`scanf` reads only one char at a time) and calling print on the next character *before* the current character.

If you swap `reverse();` and `printf("%c",c);`, you'll notice it prints the next character *after* the current character so the order is the same as the input. The key is that is it recurses before printing to reverse the character order.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if(c!='\n') this means that until we encounter a new line, the if statement will execute. So it will take input until  \n is encountered. 
Then the printf statement will executed if c=\n and it will print the last character of your input string. Consider this recursion as an example of Stack.

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void reverse() //recursive function to reverse string.
{ 
    char c;        //declare a character
    scanf("%c",&c); //scan that is get input from user in format scanf("format specifiers",&value1,&value2,.....); 

    if(c!='\n')  //check if the character is blank
    { 
      reverse();   //if blank call the method reverse() again to get get input which is not blank
      printf("%c",c);  //it will print the character from last letter to first when it is not blank
    }

}

void main()
{
  printf("\nenter a string: ");  //skips a line and asks user to enter a string
  reverse(); //calls method reverse()
  getch();

}
```

Comment: Hardly an explanation (and `\n` is _not_ a blank).